# not able to install cv2 in anaconda in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

when I tried to install tensorflow using this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pawan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 496, in _conda_info_processed
    /processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info)
  File "/home/pawan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 607, in _process_conda_info
    processed_info = info.copy()
    AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I uninstalled and then reinstalled anaconda then also I got the same error but at the end

> Preparing transaction: done
>
> Verifying transaction: done

```
Executing transaction: / Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pawan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 496, in _conda_info_processed
-     processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info)
  File "/home/pawan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 607, in _process_conda_info
    processed_info = info.copy()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'
done
```

Comment: Have you tried updating conda?
`conda update conda`, `conda update anaconda-navigator`, `conda update navigator-updater`

Comment: well i will try this...but i don't think that it will work because since i downloaded anacondas latest version from it's official website

Comment: Try `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv`